# Marque / desmarque todo los checkbox enabled en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

He visto un post similar donde tiene un código que selecciona todo los checkbox de una tabla, pero en mi tabla si tengo un checkbox con el atributo `disabled` este igual me lo selecciona.

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>
      
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1" disabled> Bar 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Que condición puedo agregarle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente diciendo que no marque los que están deshabilitados.

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
     if(!checkboxes[i].disabled){
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
       }
  }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>
      
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1" disabled> Bar 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
    </body>
    </html>
```